# How to get previous 6 months record in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a question to select previous 6 months record in SQL? Can anyone to check my code which part I get wrong?I am using MySQL query browser. Thanks.

Below is my coding:

```
SELECT id, title, contents, posted_date, action
FROM `announcement`
where posted_date >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0);
```

Below is my database info:

[image]

Actually I just want to grab previous 6 months record like below the picture:

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: I am using MySQL query browser

Comment: @AsonCheeSoon - `DateDiff` and `DateAdd` look more like MS SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: But the back-ticks are very MySQL...

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL here is the query to select rows from last 6 months:

```sql
SELECT id, title, contents, posted_date, action
FROM `announcement`
where DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), posted_date) <=180;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the last six months from *now*, just use `Now()` and `AddDate`:

```
SELECT id, title, contents, posted_date, action
FROM `announcement`
where posted_date >= AddDate(Now(), interval -6 MONTH);
```

That's for MySQL, which you've said you're using.

Your code looks more like T-SQL (MS SQL Server), though (`DateDiff`, `DateAdd`), other than the backticks. If you're using MS SQL Server, it would be `DateAdd` and `GetDate`:

```
SELECT id, title, contents, posted_date, action
FROM announcement
where DateAdd(MONTH, -6, GetDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the equivalent to your code would be:

```
SELECT id, title, contents, posted_date, action
FROM `announcement`
WHERE posted_date >= (curdate() - INTERVAL (1 - DAY(curdate()) DAY) - INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

This inner subtraction moves the date to the beginning of the current month.  Then six months are subtracted.